# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator.getOutputContext() after upgrade wildfly

Tags: java, xml, jackson, wildfly-8, wildfly-11

I was using `wildfly8` which has `jackson.core` in the 2.5 version, now I was migrating to `wildfly11` with the 2.9 version of the `jackson.core`. After upgrading the jackson dependency, I am getting the exception below.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator.getOutputContext()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/json/JsonWriteContext
```

How can I fix it without downgrading jackson to the previous version?

Comment: https://github.com/killbilling/recurly-java-library/pull/225 & https://github.com/killbilling/recurly-java-library/issues/187

Comment: Recompiling your code using Jackson 2.9 should be enough I think; they changed the return type of this method between 2.7 and 2.8. See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/313